# Custom Authoriser not called by AWS API Gateway

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, zappa

My Flask app users Facebook OAuth 2 for authorization and is deployed on API Gateway and Lambda with Zappa. The app needs to request an authorizer token and I think I need to use a custom authorizer for this as the normal lambda cannot make external requests. I have setup the resource and linked it to the custom authorizer and that to my authorizer lambda, but I am getting an error and the lambda authorizer does not appear to have been called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-api-gateway-support/endpoint+error.png

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-api-gateway-support/no+events+in+lambda+monitoring.png

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-api-gateway-support/custom+autorizer.png

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws-api-gateway-support/api+gateway+resource+setup.png

Comment: What's the error? Did you gave permission to API Gateway call your custom authorizer? Did you check cloud watch events log?

Comment: Hi, i realise that my S3 objects were not visible, now fixed.  They show the error. I think they show that API Gateway is correctly configured so that it can call the authoriser and yet the event logs are empty.

Comment: It would help if you provide the request that you are sending to api gateway. When making a request to the endpoint /callback/facebook are you sending the header "Authorization: my-token-here"?

Comment: This is the request that fails, `/callback/facebook?code=*************` where code is the users Facebook token

Comment: Try setting the http header "Authorization" in your request and see if your lambda is being called.